# Copiado de punteros Matriz

Tags: c++11

Ando poco frustrado porque no comprendo el porque esta función pone basura en vez del resultado.
Alguien por favor podría decirme ¿en que me estoy equivocando?

Uso el compilador MinGW 5 que viene en Qt.
Aquí les pongo los headers...

```
class matrix
{
    int **array, rows, columns;
public:
    //constructors that allocates memory and fills the array with 0's
    matrix();
    matrix(int side);
    matrix(int width, int height);

    int getRows() { return rows; }
    int getColumns() { return columns; }
    int getMatrix(); //returns the array atrib

    matrix operator+(const matrix &o);
    matrix operator-(const matrix &o);
    matrix operator*(const matrix &o);
    //set matrix methods write input data to the array
    void setMatrix();
    void setMatrix(int side);
    void setMatrix(int width, int height);
    void setRows(int num) { rows = num; }
    void setColumns(int num) { columns = num; }
    void print();

    ~matrix();
};
```

**Voy a poner la implementación para aclarar todo**

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <iostream>

//default constructor without parameters.
matrix::matrix()
{
    //for allocating memory since our array is a pointer.
    rows = columns = 3;
    array = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    //just for making sure we don't have garbaje.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//default constructor for square matrices.
matrix::matrix(int side)
{
    //for allocating memory since our array is a pointer.
    rows = columns = side;
    array = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    //just for making sure we don't have garbaje.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//default constructor for defining the rows and columns.
matrix::matrix(int width, int height)
{
    //for allocating memory since our array is a pointer.
    rows = width, columns = height;
    array = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    //just for making sure we don't have garbaje.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//returns a copy of the array pointer.
int matrix::getMatrix()
{
    int **copy = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        copy[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return **copy;
}

matrix matrix::operator+(const matrix &o)
{
    matrix cpy(rows, columns);
    cpy.array = getArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cpy.array[i][j] += o.array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return cpy;
}

matrix matrix::operator-(const matrix &o)
{

}

matrix matrix::operator*(const matrix &o)
{

}

//set matrix as a 3 x 3
void matrix::setMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << "[ " << i+1 << "," << j+1 << " ]: ";
            std::cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    system("cls");
}

//set matrix as a n x n
void matrix::setMatrix(int side)
{
    rows = columns = side;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << "[ " << i+1 << "," << j+1 << " ]: ";
            std::cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    system("cls");
}

//set matrix as a n x m
void matrix::setMatrix(int width, int height)
{
    rows = width, columns = height;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << "[ " << i+1 << "," << j+1 << " ]: ";
            std::cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    system("cls");
}

//this will print the matrix without problems.
void matrix::print()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        std::cout << "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << "\t" << array[i][j] ;
        }
        std::cout << "\t|";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

//default destructor for deallocating memory.
matrix::~matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        delete [] array[i];
    }
    delete [] array;

}
```

El problema esta en estos dos métodos.

```
//returns a copy of the array pointer.
int matrix::getMatrix()
{
    int **copy = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        copy[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return **copy;
}

matrix matrix::operator+(const matrix &o)
{
    matrix cpy(rows, columns);
    cpy.array = getMatrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cpy.array[i][j] += o.array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return cpy;
}
```

y finalmente el main

```
#include "matrix.h"

int main()
{
    matrix A(2);
    matrix B(2);
    matrix C(2);
    A.setMatrix();
    B.setMatrix();
    C = A + B;
    C.print();
    return 0;
}
```

**En ejecución**
Inserto 2 veces esto
[image: m1]

Luego me imprime...
[image: resp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sobre tu pregunta

**EDITADO**:

La función `getMatrix` esta retornando un `int` cuando lo que necesitas es retornar un `int **`

Por otro lado, al sobrecargar el `operator+`, el objeto `matrix cpy` que creas local es descargado al sacarlo de la pila cuando haces `return cpy;`, lo cual invoca al operador `delete` y tu memoria es liberada por el destructor, de ahí la causa que te salgan números *raros* cuando vayas a imprimir el resultado.

Para corregirlo, he modificado el `operator+` para devolver una referencia a un objeto creado dinámicamente.

Te pego el código completo en base al tuyo. Puedes también probarlo en este [enlace](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b0993de3555d2d7), ten en cuenta que yo he tenido que sustituir los `cin` para poder ejecutar el programa sin tener que teclear nada:

```
#include <iostream>

class matrix
{
    int **array, rows, columns;
public:
    //constructors that allocates memory and fills the array with 0's
    matrix();
    matrix(int side);
    matrix(int width, int height);        

    int getRows() { return rows; }
    int getColumns() { return columns; }
    int **getMatrix(); //returns the array atrib

    matrix& operator+(const matrix &o);
    //set matrix methods write input data to the array
    void setMatrix();
    void print();

    ~matrix();
};

//default constructor without parameters.
matrix::matrix()
{
    //for allocating memory since our array is a pointer.
    rows = columns = 3;
    array = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    //just for making sure we don't have garbaje.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//default constructor for square matrices.
matrix::matrix(int side)
{
    //for allocating memory since our array is a pointer.
    rows = columns = side;
    array = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    //just for making sure we don't have garbaje.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

matrix::matrix(int width, int height)
{
    //for allocating memory since our array is a pointer.
    rows = width, columns = height;
    array = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    //just for making sure we don't have garbaje.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

//returns a copy of the array pointer.
int **matrix::getMatrix()
{
    int **copy = new int*[rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        copy[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return copy;
}

matrix& matrix::operator+(const matrix &o)
{
    matrix *cpy = new matrix(rows, columns);
    cpy->array = getMatrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cpy->array[i][j] += o.array[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *cpy;
}

void matrix::setMatrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }
}

//this will print the matrix without problems.
void matrix::print()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        std::cout << "|";
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            std::cout << "\t" << array[i][j] ;
        }
        std::cout << "\t|";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


//default destructor for deallocating memory.
matrix::~matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        delete [] array[i];
    }
    delete [] array;
}

int main()
{
    matrix A(2);
    matrix B(2);
    matrix C(2);
    A.setMatrix();
    B.setMatrix();
    C = A + B;
    C.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDITADO2**: Asumir que el tamaño de un puntero es el mismo que un `int` es muy cuestionable, el tamaño de un `int` es dependiente a la plataforma y el tamaño de un puntero de la arquitectura (32bits, 64bits, etc.). Vale que te coincida en la mayoría de ocasiones... pero eso no significa que estés comparando *las mismas cosas*.

Comment: que no es lo mismo especificar `int **matrix::getMatrix()` en función que retornar `return **copy;` lo digo porque un puntero es una dirección de memoria que puede almacenarse fácilmente en el espacio de memoria de un `ìnt` que son 4 bytes, por eso pienso, que no es lo mismo? probe esa pequeña diferencia y sigue imprimiéndome basura y no se porque, sera problema del compilador?

Comment: @RenatoA. espero que te ayude la nueva edición, un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias, no tenia idea de eso de la sobrecarga